# Sorting search results (from Android SearchView query) by number of matches

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-search

i'm trying to find a good way to sort the search results according to relevance after performing a search with a SearchView in Android. For me relevance means the *number of matches* in two SQLite text columns

I'm using a CursorLoader and there the sort order can be given to the constructor at the end

```
CursorLoader tLoader = new CursorLoader(
    getActivity(), ContentProviderM.ARTICLE_CONTENT_URI,
    tProj, tSel, tSelArgs, SORT_ORDER);
```

(or set using the `setSortOrder (String sortOrder)` method)

But i need more flexibility than this because i'm looking to sort on the number of matches rather than just on one or two columns

The only solution i can see myself is to add another column in my SQLite table, do some processing, and supply that column as the sort column to the CursorLoader

Now for my question: What is the best way to supply the sort order information to the CursorLoader using SQLite syntax, avoiding having to add a new column? (And what could this SQLite code look like?) Also, i'd like to ask more in general: Is there a different solution to this problem that i've missed?

Grateful for any help! And with kind regards,
Tord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a "workaround" for this problem.

After investigating different ways to write sqlite code i ended up just adding a new table column just for sorting. This column simply stores an integer and is updated every time that the user performs a search, right before the CursorLoader is created

Advantages:

- We can now do all of the relevance calculations in Java code

Drawbacks:

- Relevance calculation is done as the search is done so if we have a large number of items it may take some time to process everything

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `content provider`, if it just pass to the `orderBy` field, you can do anything.

[SQLiteDatabase query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> **orderBy**   How to order the rows, formatted as an SQL ORDER BY clause
>   (excluding the ORDER BY itself). Passing null will use the default
>   sort order, which may be unordered.

you can do whatever you want, this is just the line after `ORDER BY`

P.S. It is totally depending on the `Content Provider`, it it choose to ignore the parameter, you can do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for this, your answer has helped me gain some clarity into this and i've updated my question

Comment: Can you provide a specific sqlite statement that i could use in a situation like this? I know it wasn't clear originally in the question but i've now updated it